# Does the game save track records?

Tags: dirt-rally

I haven't found record times for tracks anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you can view your times, but they are saved somewhere. If you go to a Custom Event, you can choose to race against your personal best time rather than the community delta or the AI. At the end of a stage, you'll see your previous best time for that track (and car?) next to the time for your current attempt.